# Why the AWS API call is getting delayed from a mobile browser?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-ec2, mobile-browser

I have deployed my Rest web services based SpringBoot java application in AWS EC2 server. Its deployed in Apache Tomcat server.

Client-side Angular4 application also deployed on the same server.

When I use a web browser from my desktop it works fine. I can see the logs are writing immediately in the server console.

But when I hit from a mobile browser I don't see any hit and logs in the server console for few minutes. But after a few seconds/minutes, I can see the logs writing on the server.

So what is wrong why it is getting delayed to reach my server from mobile browser?

Comment: What is the mobile network speed you are having? Edge/3G/HSDPA/4G?

Comment: @Ashan, Using 4G network

Comment: Can you check whether the same thing happens when you use Wifi? This is to check whether its an issue with the network

Comment: @Ashan, Its same in WiFi and mobile netwrok

Comment: Do you log the initial request of loading the index.html? or the logs you get in the server are REST API calls?

Comment: Its a REST API calls

Comment: Try doing a profiling the angular app in the web browser. I feel like there is compute heavy work happening in the app that delays the sending of the REST API (Where the computing is low compared to desktop in mobile).

Comment: @Ashan, Thanks. let me analyse my angular app and try to figure it out

Comment: I am also facing similar problem in my mobile apps. Rest API request delayed to reach server. This is not happening on mobiles only few mobiles.